# Confusion solving the equation z^2 = z

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have the following equation:

$$
z^2=z
$$
I know the solutions are supposed to be: $z= 1,0$, But I tried solving by substituting $z = x+yi $ :

$$
(x+yi)^2=x+yi
$$
$$
x^2+2xyi-y^2=x+yi
$$
Then separated the real and imaginary parts of the equation:

**Imaginary part:**
$$
2xy=y
$$
$$
y(2x-1)=0
$$

And I got $y=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}$

**Real part:**
$$
x^2-y^2=x
$$

For $y=0$:
$$
x^2=x
$$
so the solutions are $x=0$ or $x=1$

For $x=\frac{1}{2}$:
$$
(\frac{1}{2})^2-y^2=\frac{1}{2}
$$
$$
y^2 = -\frac{1}{4}
$$
$$
y=\:+\frac{1}{2}i,\:-\frac{1}{2}i
$$
And then all the solutions are:
$$
\left(0,0\right),\:\left(1,0\right),\:\left(\frac{1}{2},\:\frac{i}{2\:}\right),\:\left(\frac{1}{2},\:-\frac{i}{2}\right)
$$
But of course the last two solutions dont sustain the equation, for example:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right)^2 = \frac{i}{2\:} ≠ (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2})
$$
What Am I missing here?
Thanks

Comment: $y$ is by definition a real number, so there is no solution to the equation $y^2 = -1/4$.

Comment: You can solve it easier by not comparing real and imaginary parts, simply factor $z(z-1) = 0$

Answer (score 4):

You had $z = x + \color{red}i\cdot y$. So if you find solution $x = 1/2$, $y = i / 2$, it corresponds to $z = 1/2 + i \cdot i/2 = 0$.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you write a complex number $z$ as $x+yi$, it is implicit that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers. Therefore, the complex non-real solutions that you got are not relevant for the problem.

Anyway, writing $z$ as $x+yi$ is not a good idea here. All you have to do is\begin{align}z^2=z&\iff z^2-z=0\\&\iff z(z-1)=0\\&\iff z=0\text{ or }z-1=0\\&\iff z=0\text{ or }z=1.\end{align}

Comment: I got it. Thank You!